# When a signed contract states that a landlord has gifted white goods to a tenant, does this transfer ownership to the tenant?

Tags: gift

If a signed Addendum is attached to a tenancy agreement, stating that 'the landlord understands that the white goods have been gited to the tenant from the start of the tenancy', does this mean that the ownership of the goods has been legally transferred to the tenants?

Can the landlord then request that the white goods are returned at the end of the tenancy?

Is the tenant entitled to remove them from the property at the end of the tenancy? Can the landlord ask for them back?

If the tenant replaces the items (e.g., because they broke down) are they entitled to replace and do they own the replacement? Are they required to leave the replacement in the property?

Here is an example of such an Addendum:

"The landlord understands and the tenant agrees that all white goods e.g., washing machine and fridge freezer have been gifted to the tenants from the start of the tenancy. The landlord is not responsible for the repair or replacement of these items."

Comment: Since tenancy is generally regulated, this question can be greatly improved by adding a jurisdiction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you take back a gift?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/can-you-take-back-a-gift)

Comment: I can't think of any reason why "gift" wouldn't have its usual everyday meaning here.  If it's a gift, you own it, you can do what you like with it, and you don't have to give it back.  If you buy a new one, that one's yours too.